# ¿Por que no llega el valor que envio desde el controller al javascript de la vista?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Trabajo ASP.NET MVC, Visual Studio 2015, el problema que me esta sucediendo es que cuando doy de alta un nuevo registro me envía un json, es mas me redirecciona mostrándome el json ya que mi método es un JsonResul, entonces no es nada anormal.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Create(ClienteViewModel entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>());
                var cliente = config.CreateMapper().Map<Cliente>(entity);
                clienteService.Create(cliente);
                ModelState.Clear();
            }
            var resultado = new { guardado = true };
            return Json(resultado);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(string.Format("{ success: 'false', message: {0}}", ex.Message));
        }
    }
```

Código Ajax desde la vista.

```
function reloadTableClientes() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Cliente")',
        success: function (result) {
            //console.log("Perú esta en el mundial")
            alert("Perú esta en el mundial")
            if (result.guardado) {
                window.clientes.ajax.url('@Url.Action("ListaClientes", "Cliente")');
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Al parecer no esta enviando el valor de true que envió desde el controlador, por que si fuera así hubiera entrado al if.

En ningún momento le digo al controller que si dio de alta un registro el true lo tome el success.

Lo que intento con ese Ajax es recargar el datatable.net mediante este action del controller.

```
public JsonResult ListaClientes()
    {
        List<Cliente> _cliente = clienteService.GetAll().ToList();
        config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Cliente, ClienteViewModel>());
        List<ClienteViewModel> list = config.CreateMapper().Map<List<ClienteViewModel>>(_cliente);
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Pero si se fijan en el Ajax intento actualizar el datatable.net el cual se llama clientes mi datatable.

```
 window.clientes.ajax.url('@Url.Action("ListaClientes", "Cliente")');
```

Mi datatable.net

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clientes").DataTable({
        "language": {
            "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sSearch": "Buscar:",
            "sUrl": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primero",
                "sLast": "Último",
                "sNext": "Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        },
        ajax: {
            url: '@Url.Action("ListaClientes", "Cliente")',
    "dataSrc": ''
    },
    columns: [
        { "data": "ClienteId" },
        { "data": "RazonSocial" },
        { "data": "NumeroDocumento" },
        { "data": "Direccion" },
        { "data": "Fijo" },
        { "data": "Email" },
        { "data": "Estado" }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
        },
        "targets": 7
        },
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
        },
        "targets": 8
        }
        ]
    });
});
```

El problema es que me redirecciona a una pagina donde me muestra el json

[image: json]

El resultado que espero es que ese true vaya a mi funtion reload y entre al if y me muestre el index donde tengo mi datatable.net con el nuevo registro creado, solo que actualice el datatable mas no la pagina index.

Comment: Lo que qieres hacer en la respuesta de tu ajax es, redireccionar a otra pagina o quieres solo refrescar tu datatables despues de haber guardado los datos?

Comment: @Criss Refrescar mi datatable, mas no la page index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pude solucionarlo ya estaba cerca pero estaba obviando la view del partial view(create) la cual tuve que modificar, pasare a mostrar la implementación:

Controller JsonResult Create

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Create(ClienteViewModel entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>());
                var cliente = config.CreateMapper().Map<Cliente>(entity);
                clienteService.Create(cliente);
                ModelState.Clear();
            }
            var resultado = new { exitoso = true };
            return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var resultado = new { exitoso = false };
            return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Partial View Create se modifico el sumit

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);
        if ($form.valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {

                    if (result.exitoso) {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        window.reloadTableClientes();
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

En la view del index se pone la configuración de datatable en una variable y se crea la function reload.

```
var tableCustomer;
$(document).ready(function() {
    tableCustomer = $("#clientes").DataTable({
        "language": {
            "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sSearch": "Buscar:",
            "sUrl": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primero",
                "sLast": "Último",
                "sNext": "Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        },
        ajax: {
            url: '@Url.Action("ListaClientes", "Cliente")',
    "dataSrc": ''
    },
    columns: [
        { "data": "ClienteId" },
        { "data": "RazonSocial" },
        { "data": "NumeroDocumento" },
        { "data": "Direccion" },
        { "data": "Fijo" },
        { "data": "Email" },
        { "data": "Estado" }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
        },
        "targets": 7
        },
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
        },
        "targets": 8
        }
        ]
    });
});

function reloadTableClientes() {
    window.tableCustomer.ajax.url('@Url.Action("ListaClientes", "Cliente")').load();
};
```

Eso fueron los cambios realizados.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más recomendable es tener el mismo nombre de la bandera para no leer variables undefined. Y en estos casos los diccionarios son excelentes para retornar más de un valor, si es que lo necesitas.

```
 [HttpPost]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] no sé en que influye este tag
public JsonResult Create(ClienteViewModel entity)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>());
            var cliente = config.CreateMapper().Map<Cliente>(entity);
            clienteService.Create(cliente);
            ModelState.Clear();
        }
        result.Add("SUCCESS", true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         result.Add("SUCCESS", false); 
         result.Add("msnError", ex.Message);
    }
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Despúes guarda la configuración de tu datatable en una variable global.

```
var tabla;
$(document).ready(function() {
    tabla = $("#clientes").DataTable({
        "language": {
            "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sSearch": "Buscar:",
            "sUrl": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primero",
                "sLast": "Último",
                "sNext": "Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        },
        ajax: {
            url: '@Url.Action("ListaClientes", "Cliente")',
    "dataSrc": ''
    },
    columns: [
        { "data": "ClienteId" },
        { "data": "RazonSocial" },
        { "data": "NumeroDocumento" },
        { "data": "Direccion" },
        { "data": "Fijo" },
        { "data": "Email" },
        { "data": "Estado" }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
        },
        "targets": 7
        },
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
        },
        "targets": 8
        }
        ]
    });
});
```

Y al ajax hay que asignar su función de error. Y para refrescar la tabla, usa la funcion reload, ya que al llamar solo a tu controlador te retonara la lista a la página, no a la tabla.

```
function reloadTableClientes() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Cliente")',
        success: function (result) {
            //console.log("Perú esta en el mundial")
            alert("Perú esta en el mundial")
            if (result.SUCCESS)
                 tabla.ajax.reload();
        },
        error: function (response) {
            //lo que necesitas en caso de que truene tu controllador
                }
    });
};
```